# Jersey framework override controller methods or REST request filtering

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I need to implement a controller for processing requests whith filter use Jersey framework. For example:

.../myservice/book - display a list of all books.

.../myservice/book?chapter=1,5 - display 1 and 5 books chapters.

.../myservice/book?page=10,50 - display 10 and 50 books pages.

.../myservice/book?chapter=1,5&page=10,50 - display 1 and 5 books chapters and only 10 and 50 book pages.

I can't use .../myservice/book/chapter/1,5/page/10,50, because possible situation:
.../myservice/book/7 - display book 7 and filters described above can be applied here.
Is it possible to implement it in this way?:

```
public class TestController {

@Path("/book")
@GET
public Object getBook() {
    // return a list of all books
}

public Object getBook(@QueryParam("chapter") String chapter) {
    // return books chapters    
}

public Object getBook(@QueryParam("page") String page) {
    // return books pages   
}

public Object getBook(@QueryParam("chapter") String page, @QueryParam("page") String page) {
    //  return books chapters and pages
    }
}
```

Or to add all kinds of filters in one method and verify the presence of a large number of conditions?

Comment: DannyMo, thank you so much for answer. I'll do as you suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have the same path map to multiple resource methods. You'll either have to provide separate paths or use a single method. I would choose the latter and then delegate to other helper methods:

```
@Path("/book")
@GET
public Object getBooks(@QueryParam("chapter") String chapter, @QueryParam("page") String page) {
    if (chapter == null && page == null)
      return getAllBooks();
    else if (chapter == null)
      return getBooksByPages(...);
    else if (page == null)
      return getBooksByChapters(...);
    else
      return getBooksByPagesAndChapters(...);
}
```

Side note: instead of passing in your pages and chapters as a comma-separated strings, you can use multiple query parameters: `.../myservice/book?chapter=1&chapter=5` and Jersey will throw them into a list for you: `@QueryParam("chapter") List<String> chapters`